How to deal with mediapipe Plugin build Error
I'm trying to follow the MediaPipe Unity Plugin setting now but it doesn't work...

OS : Window 11 Pro
Bazel Version : 5.1.0
OpenCV : 3.4.15
Python : 3.11.5
Nuget : 5.10.0

I followed all setting
set BAZEL_VS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional
set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC
set BAZEL_WINSDK_FULL_VERSION=10.0.18362.0
set BAZEL_VC_FULL_VERSION=14.39.33519

but there are some errors
INFO (build.py): Building protobuf sources...
DEBUG (build.py): Running `bazel --output_user_root C:/_bzl build -c opt --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C://Users//PC//MediaPipeUnityPlugin//env//Scripts//python.exe //mediapipe_api:mediapipe_proto_srcs`
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_absl' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_protobuf' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_googletest' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_github_gflags_gflags' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'rules_python' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_apple' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_swift' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_apple_support' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'bazel_skylib' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'pybind11' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/tf_runtime/third_party/cuda/dependencies.bzl:51:10: The following command will download NVIDIA proprietary software. By using the software you agree to comply with the terms of the license agreement that accompanies the software. If you do not agree to the terms of the license agreement, do not use the software.
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_python' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1564776078 -0400"
DEBUG: Repository rules_python instantiated at:
  C:/users/pc/mediapipeunityplugin/WORKSPACE:34:23: in <toplevel>
  C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/rules_pkg/deps.bzl:33:10: in rules_pkg_dependencies
  C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl:233:18: in maybe
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:199:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: C:/users/pc/mediapipeunityplugin/WORKSPACE:288:23: fetching android_ndk_repository rule //external:androidndk: Either the path attribute of android_ndk_repository or the ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable must be set.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe_api:mediapipe_proto_srcs' failed; build aborted: Either the path attribute of android_ndk_repository or the ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable must be set.
INFO: Elapsed time: 28.757s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (15 packages loaded, 22 targets configured)
    currently loading: @com_google_mediapipe//mediapipe/framework/formats ... (9 packages)
    Fetching @local_execution_config_python; fetching
    Fetching @local_jdk; Restarting.
    Fetching @ninja_1.10.2_toolchains; fetching
    Fetching @com_google_protobuf; Restarting.

it says that I didn't set ANDROID_NDK_HOME so I set the android ndk 27.0.11718014
set ANDROID_NDK_HOME=C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\27.0.11718014

but error again
INFO (build.py): Building protobuf sources...
DEBUG (build.py): Running `bazel --output_user_root C:/_bzl build -c opt --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C://Users//PC//MediaPipeUnityPlugin//env//Scripts//python.exe //mediapipe_api:mediapipe_proto_srcs`
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_absl' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_protobuf' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_googletest' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_github_gflags_gflags' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'rules_python' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_apple' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_swift' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_apple_support' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'bazel_skylib' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'pybind11' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/tf_runtime/third_party/cuda/dependencies.bzl:51:10: The following command will download NVIDIA proprietary software. By using the software you agree to comply with the terms of the license agreement that accompanies the software. If you do not agree to the terms of the license agreement, do not use the software.
ERROR: C:/users/pc/mediapipeunityplugin/WORKSPACE:288:23: fetching android_ndk_repository rule //external:androidndk: java.io.IOException: Expected directory at C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.11718014/platforms but it is not a directory or it does not exist. Unable to read the Android NDK at C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.11718014, the path may be invalid. Is the path in android_ndk_repository() or ANDROID_NDK_HOME set correctly? If the path is correct, the contents in the Android NDK directory may have been modified.
INFO: Repository com_google_protobuf instantiated at:
  C:/users/pc/mediapipeunityplugin/WORKSPACE:177:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:353:31: in <toplevel>
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_python' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1564776078 -0400"
DEBUG: Repository rules_python instantiated at:
  C:/users/pc/mediapipeunityplugin/WORKSPACE:34:23: in <toplevel>
  C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/rules_pkg/deps.bzl:33:10: in rules_pkg_dependencies
  C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl:233:18: in maybe
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  C:/_bzl/jstjscom/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:199:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe_api:mediapipe_proto_srcs' failed; build aborted: Expected directory at C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.11718014/platforms but it is not a directory or it does not exist. Unable to read the Android NDK at C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.11718014, the path may be invalid. Is the path in android_ndk_repository() or ANDROID_NDK_HOME set correctly? If the path is correct, the contents in the Android NDK directory may have been modified.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.173s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (30 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
    currently loading: @com_google_mediapipe//mediapipe/modules/face_geometry/protos ... (7 packages)
    Fetching @local_execution_config_python; fetching
    Fetching @rules_foreign_cc_commands_overloads; fetching

I did downgrade a version of ndk once, but the result was same..
Could you guide me...?
